# Drush rsync code 23 error

Tags: rsync, drush

I have a path issue. I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this code 23 error. Here is the complete error message: I am guessing that rsync cant write to my local /private/tmp directory.

Here is the output:

```
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
rsync: link_stat "/tmp/SGDU55.sql" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(1400) [receiver=2.6.9]
Could not rsync from xxx@staging-5244.prod.xxx.com:/tmp/SGDU55.sql to                              [error]
/private/tmp/-to-drupal_db.sql.p0YIBu

```

Here is the drush simulate command abbreviated output.
```

$ drush sql-sync @aq6 @aqsolo --simulate

.....

Calling system(rsync -e 'ssh -i /Users/dave.ferrera/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key' -akz --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitignore" --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".hgignore" --exclude=".hgrags" --exclude=".bzr" --exclude=".bzrignore" --exclude=".bzrtags" --exclude=".svn" /private/tmp/-to-drupal_db.sql.iXOzSo vagrant@12.12.12.12:tmp/drupal_db.sql);

Calling system(ssh -i /Users/dave.ferrera/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key vagrant@12.12.12.12 'mysql --database=drupal_db --host=localhost --user=root --password=password --silent < tmp/drupal_db.sql 2>&1');

$

```

Is there a way change the /private/tmp path to something else?
I have added chmod 1777 to /private and /private/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using Acquia the problem seemed to be solved as soon as I changed to the correct %dum-dir path.

so now I have:

```
 '%dump-dir' => '/mnt/tmp/',
```

If you alias root is beginning with `'root' => '/mnt/gfs.....` than it should be the same.